# Export resources in one single file and read from SD card

Tags: android, resources, sd-card, android-sdcard

I want to export my android app resources (all of images, videos, etc.) to one single file and read it from the SD card.  This is about a educational app -- I want to install my app in the phone's memory and read the data from the SD card because user may change their SD card and load new data.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

What basically you can do is Create  single folder on SD Card and dump all information
there.You application can read all files from that folder.

You can access folder on your SD card by writing

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath+"/MyDirecotry/"+abc.mp4;
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath+"/MyDirecotry/"+abc.jpg;
```

Comment: I know that I can read files from my SD Card in directories, but I don't want these files be accessible out of my app from file manager. Is there a way to secure these files? I want only my app can read the files. Even the user couldn't open the files with USB ram readers in PC

Answer (score 0):

For installing app in phone memory use below code

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example11"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" **android:installLocation="internalOnly"**>
```

You should make a single zipFile of your content using code you extract it on sdcard then access content form sdCard.

I hope its helpful to you.

Comment: I know that I can read files from my SD Card in directories, but I don't want these files be accessible out of my app from file manager. Is there a way to secure these files? I want only my app can read the files. Even the user couldn't open the files with USB ram readers in PC